# Problem supporting multiple resolutions on Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-assets

I'm having a weird problem. I have been testing my app with hdpi resources up until recently. My designer sent over some mdpi assets and now my application is defaulting to the mdpi assets. How can I make sure the hdpi assets are being used for my phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your device was defaulting to the hdpi graphics because there were no other graphics available. but since you now added mdpi, your phone has a choice between the 2 and it will choose the most compatible for the device.  you can't force your application to use HDPI unless you only supply the HDPI graphics

Answer (score 1):

You cant, the hdpi, mdpi etc are handset attributes. If you design the app correctly you will have an asset hierarchy that will address all screen densities. So I recommend that you focus on that.

To elaborate, for a robust android app, you will have resources in hdpi, mdpi, ldpi and xdpi folders, maybe even ndpi folders, all based on a well defined asset heirarchy. You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Comment: I have hdpi, mdpi, ldpi and xdpi assets. Prior to introducing them, I only had hdpi, and the phone seemed to default to that. Because I introduced mdpi, my phone is now automatically referring to that and no longer hdpi?

Comment: Interestingly, bumping my minSDK up to 4, changed things and now hdpi is being used.

Comment: This is a bit of a candy debugging thing, I recommend reading the link I provided and creating a correct asset folder organization. I will save a lot of headache later on.